# Why is the Object data not displayed in the browser when used inside JSX?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

I have a React Container that is connected to Redux Store. My Redux Store has an array of data which i consume in mapStateToProps. But I am unable to use it inside JSX. There is no error. However, Nothing is displayed in the browser. Console logging the object gives the properties.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class CurrentStore extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props.current);
    return (
      <div className='centered row'>
        <div className='column'>
          {this.props.current.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    current: state.app.stores.filter(s => s._id === ownProps.match.params.storeId)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CurrentStore);
```

Comment: `filter` gives you an array of objects back, so aren't you missing a `map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) gives you an array of values back, which means that your `current` object is in fact an array of objects.

So either, you should change your mapStateToProps to return the first value, like:

```
function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    current: state.app.stores.filter(s => s._id === ownProps.match.params.storeId)[0]
  }
}
```

, or you should do it in the render function (which looks lots more appropriate)

```
class CurrentStore extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props.current);
    return (
      <div className='centered row'>
          { this.props.current && this.props.current.map( item => <div className='column'>{ item.name }</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the render it is now possible that more than 1 item would be returned, in case you don't want that, you could change the render to take only the first item

```
class CurrentStore extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let { current } = this.props;
    if (!current || !current[0]) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
      <div className='centered row'>
          <div className='column'>{ current[0].name }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @AdityaPS You are welcome, seen that you have a 0 % acceptance rate for your questions, feel free to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) through on how to accept answers